# Forward function to a ScalaTest macro

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am converting some QUnit Javascript tests to Scala. The tests I have look like this:

```
class XXX extends MyTests {
  test("equals", () => {
    val a = new XXX(x)
    val b = new XXX(y)
    ok(a.x != b.x, "Passed!")
    ok(a.y != b.y, "Passed!")
    ok(!a.equals(b), "Passed!")
    ok(!b.equals(a), "Passed!")
    a.copy(b)
    ok(a.x == b.x, "Passed!")
    ok(a.y == b.y, "Passed!")
    ok(a.equals(b), "Passed!")
    ok(b.equals(a), "Passed!")
  })
}
```

`MyTests` is my trait derived from ScalaTest `FunSuite`

I could replace `ok` with `assert` in the code, or I can place following in `MyTests`:

```
def ok(ok: Boolean, message: String) = assert(ok, message)
```

First solution results in better tests, as using `assert` directly means `ScalaTest` enhanced macro implementation of `assert` is used. Second solution is much less work, as I do not have to replace `ok` in the code.

Is there some way how to import `assert` under a different name from `FunSuite` or otherwise forward my implementation to the ScalaTest macro, so that `ok` behaves exactly as `assert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.scalatest.Assertions.{assert => ok}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine, the only drawback is I cannot do this in `MyTests`, I need to repeat this in each test suite (imports are not inherited). Would it be possible to do something in `MyTests` only?

Comment: Sure, just `def ok(...) = org.scalatest.Assertions.assert(...)`, refer to scalatest source code for the list of arguments.

Comment: That would be the same as the "Second solution" mentioned in the question, which unfortunately does not work well, as the macro is not receiving arguments from the `ok` callsite, but from inside of `ok`, where the argument is already a simple `Boolean`. One would need to provide a macro instead of a normal function for this to work.

Comment: No, in your example you are doing `def ok(...) = scala.Predef.assert(...)`, which is not what you want. You can also manually inline the definition of scalatest assert if forwarding doesn't work. My point is: just look at the damn source code and see how it works!

Comment: No, I am not. `MyTests` inherits from `FunSuite`, therefore `assert` is taken from ScalaTest `Assertions`, not from `scala.Predef`. I cannot manually inline definition of the ScalaTest `assert`, as the macro implementation is package private.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you figured out it's impossible :).